# Chrome browser is getting hanged with Knockoutjs context debugger

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js

I am a web developer. One of the js Library we use in our web application is knockout js. To make it easier to debug we use Knockoutjs context debugger plugin. However when ever we inspect any element and trying to view knockout objects on Knockout Context tab in Chrome inspector, the browser is hanging and then crashing.
At that point of time when I open the Task manager the chorme.exe is taking high memory than any application.

**Steps to Reproduce this issue:**
1. Install knockout context debugger plugin for chrome browser.
2. Open any single page web application  which have at least 25 view models which are worked together in the application in chrome.
3. Open inspector and try to inspect any element which has knockout bindings.

The browser will be going into unresponsive, then hangs and eventually crashes

How to resolve this problem with out uninstalling Knockout context debugger plugin?

**Edit Based on comments:**
It is also happening in my colleagues machine as well. They are also facing this problem

Comment: This sounds more like a problem you should report to the maker of the plugin, not something you should ask about on SO.

Comment: @Retsam, Why not, There is answer for this question. But you don't know that answer

Comment: @Ramya Sure, *there exists* an answer; but that doesn't make the question "answerable".  I'm not seeing that behavior, the OP hasn't given any way to reproduce that behavior, the *question* is "this doesn't work on my machine, why?", which isn't really a question.

Comment: From the doc, off-topic questions include: "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced".

Comment: @Retsam,The rule doesn't applicable for this question as it is globally reproducible. Since it is globally reproducible there is big discussion thread about it.

Comment: @Retsam, This question is perfectly answerable as the question and scenario is valid. It is you that don't understand it and not seeing answerable because you doesn't have sufficient knowledge about the subject that OP is talking. If you don't understand just ask for more information. But don't mislead OP with your insufficient knowledge.

Comment: If this depends on the plugin, you should probably take it up with the plugin author's mailing list or other channel. This is just on the line between on and off topic, as problems with the plugin are definitely off, but programming tools are on-topic.

Comment: @Ramya I haven't seen evidence that it's "globally reproducible".  I have followed the steps that were edited onto the question, and I'm still not seeing the issue.  

Just because you've googled and found other people having similar symptoms doesn't mean it's the same issue.  You literally cannot know that.

Answer (score 3):

The browser hangs for various reasons. Mostly due to below reasons. Some of them are
Serialization of DOM elements, Circular reference etc..

The most common root cause for this problem is you might enable serialize option in knockout context debugger options. Below is the resolution for that problem

Go to Chrome settiongs--> Extensions--> Knockout Context debugger--> Options

Deselect Serialize (provides the best visualization) checkbox if it is already selected

Below discussion thread discusses in detail about various reasons behind the hanging of browser

[Constantly hangs the browser](https://github.com/timstuyckens/chromeextensions-knockoutjs/issues/9)

Comment: Is there a way to detect if your view model is non-serializeable? I'm running a fairly complex app and it utilizes various dependent libraries, and so I'd like to just be able to scan a json root for invalid elements that I can track down and fix.

Comment: Not sure why with this project, but the debugger attached was sending my memory usage up to a gig and then crashes.  Never had problems with any other knockout projects.  The fix in this answer stopped the crashes for my case.